# How to upgrade to NativeScript 5?

Tags: nativescript, upgrade, nativescript-angular

I have a mobile app on NativeScript 4.2 with Angular. How do I upgrade to NativeScript 5.0?

I also would like to start using the preview app from the NativeScript CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the upgrade instructions at https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions. The page also has a link to breaking changes.

Here's a summary of the commands.

```
# NativeScript CLI
npm install -g nativescript

# Application Upgrade
tns update

# Platform Upgrade
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios

# tns-core-modules Upgrade
npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save

# TypeScript Upgrade
npm i nativescript-dev-typescript@latest --save-dev
./node_modules/.bin/ns-upgrade-tsconfig

# Angular Upgrade
npm i nativescript-angular@latest --save
./node_modules/.bin/update-app-ng-deps
npm i

# Webpack Upgrade
npm i nativescript-dev-webpack --save-dev
./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs
```

For Windows users, user the Windows path separators and the .cmd file extension.

```
.\node_modules\.bin\ns-upgrade-tsconfig.cmd
.\node_modules\.bin\update-app-ng-deps.cmd
.\node_modules\.bin\update-ns-webpack.cmd --deps --configs
```

I'm also using NativeScript UI. Here are the commands I had to run.

```
tns plugin remove nativescript-ui-sidedrawer
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-sidedrawer

tns plugin remove nativescript-ui-dataform
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-dataform

...
```

Confirm you are using the latest version by running tns info.

```
tns info
```

You can now use the Preview app. Run the command.

```
tns preview
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the [**Migration Steps to NativeScript 5.0** article](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/wiki/Migration-Steps-to-NativeScript-5.0).